# Recognizing a Higher Percentage of Multiple Barcodes from an Image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, code-request, code-review, computer-vision

I would like a path or way to find barcodes in an image and read more of them and ideally quicker (It is very slow for an image).

So, `BarcodeRecognize[]` already recognizes multiple barcodes in an image and reads them. But I would not say that it is partically great by itself. I have 4 examples. Also, near the bottom I have the code to generate multiple barcodes in a collage which can be used to make real stickers or be an ideal digital image only.

For example, it only calculates 4 of the barcodes,`{VF0olZI14,u7QuPYD7uD3J5W,hEOAqfV1,whmVd9rHfYh0}`, from the image below but clearly there are many more than 4:

[image: This is a collage of random barcodes in a png file.]

when I used real barcodes, it only calculated, `aI8F2lFt`, from:

[image: 3 barcodes. They are rotated and real ones on a box.]

and it only gave `Z13` for:
[image: This has fewer barcodes with some cut off. But several of them are clear.]

This being said, I think it worked perfectly for the one below by giving the five values `{044000033385,4000033382,VF0olZI14,4000033382,044000033382}` for:

[image: This is an image with 5 barcodes. It was read perfectly.]

And here is the code for making a sticker collage:

```
barcodeFormats={"Aztec","Codabar","Code128","Code39","Code93","DataMatrix","EAN13","EAN8","ITF","PDF417","QR","UPC","UPCE"};
allowedColorCombinations={
{RGBColor[0,0,0], RGBColor[1,1,1]},{RGBColor[1,0,0], RGBColor[0,1,1]},
{RGBColor[0,1,0], RGBColor[1,0,1]},{RGBColor[0,0,1], RGBColor[1,1,0]},
{RGBColor[1,1,1], RGBColor[0,0,0]},{RGBColor[0,1,1], RGBColor[1,0,0]},
{RGBColor[1,0,1], RGBColor[0,1,0]},{RGBColor[1,1,0], RGBColor[0,0,1]}
};

barCodeGenerator[format_,chosenColorCombination_] :=
Module[
  {numericList, alphaNumericList,alphaNumericCapitalList ,alphaNumericSpecialList,fullSpecialCharacterList, partialSpecialCharacterList, level, barcode,string1,string2},
  
numericList = CharacterRange["0", "9"];
alphaNumericList = Join[CharacterRange["0", "9"], CharacterRange["A", "Z"], CharacterRange["a", "z"]];
alphaNumericCapitalList = Join[CharacterRange["0", "9"], CharacterRange["A", "Z"]];
alphaNumericSpecialList=Join[CharacterRange["0", "9"], CharacterRange["A", "Z"], CharacterRange["a", "z"],{ "-", ".", "$", "/", "+", "%", " "}];
fullSpecialCharacterList ={ "-", ".", "$", "/", "+", "%", " "};
 partialSpecialCharacterList={"-","$",".","/","+"};
   

  Switch[format,
    "Aztec" | "PDF417" | "QR",
    barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[alphaNumericSpecialList, RandomInteger[{8, 200}]]];
    level = RandomInteger[{0, 8}];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, {format, level}],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
 "Code39" ,
 string1=StringJoin[RandomChoice[alphaNumericCapitalList, RandomInteger[{1, 66}]]];
 string2=StringJoin[RandomChoice[fullSpecialCharacterList, RandomInteger[{1, 14}]]];
 barcode=StringJoin[RandomSample[Join[Characters[string1], Characters[string2]]]];
   ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
 "Code93" ,
 string1=StringJoin[RandomChoice[alphaNumericCapitalList, RandomInteger[{1, 66}]]];
 string2=StringJoin[RandomChoice[fullSpecialCharacterList, RandomInteger[{1, 14}]]];
 barcode=StringJoin[RandomSample[Join[Characters[string1], Characters[string2]]]];
   ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
    "Code128"  ,
    barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[alphaNumericSpecialList, RandomInteger[{1, 80}]]];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
 "Codabar",
 string1=StringJoin[RandomChoice[numericList, RandomInteger[{1, 100}]]];
 string2=StringJoin[RandomChoice[partialSpecialCharacterList, RandomInteger[{1, 14}]]];
 barcode=StringJoin[RandomSample[Join[Characters[string1], Characters[string2]]]];
 ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
 
 "DataMatrix",
 barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[alphaNumericList, RandomInteger[{8, 14}]],RandomChoice[{"-","$",":","/","."}]];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
    "ITF",
    barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[numericList, RandomChoice[Table[2*i, {i, 3, 40}]]]];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
    "EAN13",
    barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[numericList, 13]];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
    "UPC",
    barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[numericList, 12]];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
   "EAN8" ,
  barcode = StringJoin[RandomChoice[numericList, 8]];
     ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}],
    
  "UPCE",
    barcode = StringJoin[Join[{RandomChoice[{"0","1"}]},RandomChoice[numericList, RandomChoice[{6,7}]]]];
    ColorReplace[BarcodeImage[barcode, format],{Black->chosenColorCombination[[1]],White->chosenColorCombination[[2]]}]
   
  ]
  
  (*barcode*)
]

(* Initialize an empty list for successful barcode generations *)
successfulBarcodes = {};
(* Desired number of successful barcode generations *)
desiredSuccesses = 20;
(* Counter for successful generations *)
successCount = 0;
(* Maximum number of attempts to avoid infinite loop *)
maxAttempts = 100;
attempts = 0;
While[successCount < desiredSuccesses && attempts < maxAttempts,
  (* Attempt to generate a barcode, suppressing warnings/errors *)
  result = Quiet[Check[
    barCodeGenerator[RandomChoice[barcodeFormats], RandomChoice[allowedColorCombinations]],
    "Error"
  ]];
  
  (* Check if the generation was successful *)
  If[result =!= "Error",
    (* If successful, append to the list and increment the counter *)
    AppendTo[successfulBarcodes, result];
    successCount++;
  ];
  
  (* Increment the attempts counter *)
  attempts++;
]
(* successfulBarcodes now contains the successful barcode generations, up to the desired number or the attempt limit *)

Rasterize[ImageCollage[successfulBarcodes,"Stretch",{825 , 1150},ImagePadding->10,Background->RGBColor[.5,.5,.5]]]
```

Lastly, this is a photo of a wooden pallet with empty boxes on them with stickers made from Mathematica in my garage. While I don't expect it to be able to be read, I thought this was a good place for Show & Tell. I call this sculpture, "Empty Boxes on a Pallet". Some people play the guitar as a hobby, but I do this...

[image: Empty Boxes on a Pallet]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. Hopefully someone else can improve it.

`BarcodeRecognize` seems to work better with isolated barcodes. This can be accomplished using `MorphologicalComponents`, if the barcodes are well separated.

```
img2 = ColorNegate[Binarize[img, .5]]
```

[image]

```
img3 = Dilation[img2, DiskMatrix[5]]
```

[image]

```
comps = MorphologicalComponents[img3, .01, Method -> "BoundingBox"];
comps // Colorize
```

[image]

`ComponentMeasurements` can now be used to extract each barcode

```
barcodes = ComponentMeasurements[{img, comps}, "Image"][[All, 2]]
```

[image]

For some barcodes, `BarcodeRecognize` returns the same result for the original and color inverted images, and for some only the inverted one works. This decodes 26 of the 40 barcodes:

```
BarcodeRecognize /@ ColorNegate[barcodes] /. {} -> Nothing
```

> {"Z20aHSN1q-", "XXc5EIsPc-", "RsEMPkIXP-", "cxWXUX5pmKAWh", 
> "ZzFgrlIX", "OgYFuUdue", "RRS4K2kvV", "LOT4qMeOK", "5839218585789", 
> "VF0olZI14", "Yu8up3lWEzQt8U/", "JVqusjCx3GSN3Y/", "eB7npKSnBJZH-", 
> "Vg6W92475Tv0y", "sUhAv0yLSGb/", "SKlJDYqEWgOcQ4", "uIf471MW/", 
> "cEucOXc90", "aZVZYcYx3PAjTL", "XqRf07XAtzm", "aI8F2lFt", "hEOAqfV1", 
> "F8V0Kin1xvIK18", "Z1PUfv5Uq9", "whmVd9rHfYh0", "u7QuPYD7uD3J5W"}

### Edited to show which barcodes worked

`BarcodeRecognize` performance appears to be worse with 1D and high-density 2D barcodes.

```
SortBy[Transpose[{barcodes, 
    BarcodeRecognize /@ ColorNegate[barcodes]}], Last] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about ComponentMeasurements. I am curious now about which types it reads better or worse for now.

Comment: @TegLouis - Edited answer to show which ones worked